# Get only the last comment from order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, status

I'm using an observer to watch `<sales_order_status_history_save_after>`, but it returns ALL comments, how can I get just the last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code to get latest comment.

```
<?php
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$history = $order->getStatusHistoryCollection()->getFirstItem();
echo $history->getComment();
?>
```

Comment: Can i get help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/298382/57334 @Abhishek Panchal