# Magento 1.9 - How to get shipped date and display on Customer account My Order?

Tags: magento-1.9, date, shipment

Backend generate date when we shipped order,

[image]

Frontend shown only order created dated,

[image]

Is it possible using event-observer?

Comment: while you see shipment? you need to show shipment date not a order date right?

Comment: @PadhiyarGaurang I need to show both dates. By default ordered date shown once order created also need if order comment status update to shipped [ https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCBkq.png ] the shipment date should be display.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved this for you.

**sales.xml** at app/design/frontend/{namespace}/{theme}/layout/sales.xml update below code.

```
<sales_order_shipment translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account Order Shipment View</label>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="sales/order_info" as="info" name="sales.order.info" template="sales/order/shipment/info.phtml">
            <block type="sales/order_info_buttons" as="buttons" name="sales.order.info.buttons" />
        </block>
        <block type="sales/order_shipment" name="sales.order.shipment">
            <block type="sales/order_shipment_items" name="shipment_items" template="sales/order/shipment/items.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_default</block><template>sales/order/shipment/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="sales/order_comments" name="shipment_comments" template="sales/order/comments.phtml" />
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="sales.order.info">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>view</name><path>*/*/view</path><label>Order Information</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>invoice</name><path>*/*/invoice</path><label>Invoices</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>shipment</name><path></path><label>Shipments</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>creditmemo</name><path>*/*/creditmemo</path><label>Refunds</label></action>
    </reference>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
</sales_order_shipment>
```

Than 
create file **info.phtml** at app/design/frontend/{theme_namespace}/{theme}/template/sales/order/shipment/info.phtml

```
<?php /** @var $this Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Info */ ?>
<?php $_order = $this->getOrder() ?>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>
<div class="page-title title-buttons">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Order #%s - %s', $_order->getRealOrderId(), $_order->getStatusLabel()) ?></h1>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('buttons') ?>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getStatusHistoryRssUrl($_order) ?>
<dl class="order-info">
    <dt><?php echo $this->__('About This Order:') ?></dt>
    <dd>
        <?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
        <ul id="order-info-tabs">
        <?php foreach ($_links as $_link): ?>
            <?php if($_link->getUrl()): ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a></li>
            <?php else: ?>
                <li class="current"><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($('order-info-tabs').select('LI'),['first','last']);</script>
    </dd>
</dl>
<p class="order-date"><?php echo $this->__('Order Date: %s', $this->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), 'long')) ?></p>
<?php $shipment = $_order->getShipmentsCollection();?>
<?php if(count($shipment) > 1): ?>
    <?php foreach($shipment as $_shipment): ?>
        <p class="shipment-date">
            <?php echo $this->__('#'.$_shipment->getIncrementId().' '.'Shipment Date: %s', $this->formatDate($_shipment->getCreatedAt(), 'long')) ?>
        </p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php elseif(count($shipment) == '1'):?>
    <p class="shipment-date">
        <?php echo $this->__('Shipment Date: %s', $this->formatDate($shipment->getFirstItem()->getCreatedAt(), 'long')) ?>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (!$_order->getIsVirtual()): ?>
<div class="col2-set order-info-box">
    <div class="col-1">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-title">
                <h2><?php echo $this->__('Shipping Address') ?></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="box-content">
                <address><?php echo $_order->getShippingAddress()->format('html') ?></address>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-title">
                <h2><?php echo $this->__('Shipping Method') ?></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="box-content">
                <?php if ($_order->getShippingDescription()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingDescription()) ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('No shipping information available'); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="col2-set order-info-box">
    <div class="col-1">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-title">
                <h2><?php echo $this->__('Billing Address') ?></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="box-content">
                <address><?php echo $_order->getBillingAddress()->format('html') ?></address>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <div class="box box-payment">
            <div class="box-title">
                <h2><?php echo $this->__('Payment Method') ?></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="box-content">
                <?php echo $this->getPaymentInfoHtml() ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This solution worked for multi shipment and single shipment both.

**Update :** 
Cache flush after this.

Comment: After update with your code may i know where will shown shipped date, https://imgur.com/qZ6scR0

Comment: @zus
Multi Shipment : https://prnt.sc/q9odqr
Single Shipment: https://prnt.sc/q9odok

Comment: okay, let me create new order.

Comment: May i know why its not applied for already shipped order?

Comment: folder structure : app/design/frontend/default/theme/layout/sales.xml & app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/sales/order/shipment/info.phtml

Comment: whichever order are shipped it will apply on those. Orders like has virtual products which are shipable does not work on that

Comment: use in your current theme. What is your current theme?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102104/discussion-between-zus-and-padhiyar-gaurang).